# UINavigationController pushViewController pushes controller then "automatically" dismiss it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

In my `HomeViewController's` `viewDidAppear` method, I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL didRunBefore = [defaults boolForKey:@"didRunBefore"];

    if (!didRunBefore) {
        // check to see if children already exist (previous user)
        NSArray *children = [CoreDataHelper getObjectsForEntity:NSStringFromClass([Child class]) withSortKey:@"name" andSortAscending:YES andContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        if (children.count == 0) {
            // send user to create fist child
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

            ChildEditTableViewController *editController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildEditControllerID"];

            NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            newContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
            editController.managedObjectContext = newContext;

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:editController animated:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code from ViewDidLoad in ChildEditTableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Child Edit controller loaded");

    self.availablePicker.delegate = self;
    self.bankedPicker.delegate = self;

    self.carryOverCellIsShowing = NO;

    self.isNewChild = self.child == nil;

    self.imageButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageButton.frame.size.width/2;
    self.imageButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [[self.imageButton imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

    if (self.isNewChild) {

        // check to see if it's user's first time running app
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        BOOL didRunBefore = [defaults boolForKey:@"didRunBefore"];

        if (!didRunBefore) {
            // hide Home back button
            [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

            // update didRunBefore to yes
            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"didRunBefore"];
            [defaults synchronize];
        }

        self.child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Add New", @"Add New Title");
    }
    else {
        if (self.child.profileImage != nil) {

            [self.imageButton setImage:[UIImage squaredImageFromImage:[UIImage imageWithData:self.child.profileImage] scaledToSize:self.imageButton.frame.size.height] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        self.name.text = self.child.name;

        self.autoBankSwitch.on = [self.child.autoBank boolValue];
        self.carryOverSwitch.on = ![self.child.resetDailyTotal boolValue];

        [self setCarryOverSwitchVisibility:self.autoBankSwitch];
    }

    // This will remove extra separators from tableview
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

That code works fine as far as I can see the `ChildEditTableViewController` load on the screen, but then it automatically pops back to the home controller. I've checked the code in the child controller and the only time I pop the controller is when the user hits a button.

Here's the Save IBAction where I pop the controller:

```
- (IBAction)save:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    [self saveToDB:sender];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If I use `self.navigationController setViewControllers` instead, this does not happen and `ChildEditTableViewController` stays loaded on the screen, but clicking the Save button (which pops the view controller) doesn't do anything.

Any ideas? (Thanks!)

**** EDIT *****
I noticed it was working fine in iOS 7.1 and 7.03. The only difference from an UI perspective was this piece of code below:

```
// enable handling of push notifications
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    // use registerUserNotificationSettings
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
    // use registerForRemoteNotifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

In iOS 8 I was getting a prompt to allow notifications on the simulator (something that doesn't work on the sim in prior versions). After I clicked ok is when the EditChild controller would get popped. So I commented out that code in the app delegate and the controller stays loaded just like in iOS 7.

****** EDIT ******
Below is the ApplicationDidBecomeActive code

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.


    // move user to home screen so app is locked each time they open it (but not on first use)

    SWRevealViewController* revealController = (SWRevealViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)revealController.frontViewController;

    [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So this is the culprit. This code is getting called again right after the user clicks Accept on the notifications registration alert, for some crazy reason.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, so your problem has to be in the ChildEditTableViewController. Also, your last line doesn't make sense -- It doesn't matter if the controller wasn't pushed. If you set the viewControllers (Assuming you passed the ChildEditTableViewController), that adds the controller(s) to the stack, and you should be able to pop the top one off just as if you had pushed it in the first place. 
Do you have any segues set up in the storyboard that might be interfering? You should post the code from viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear for ChildEditTableViewController.

Comment: I added the ViewDidLoad code and updated my last line to just describe the behavior I'm seeing since I don't know what's going on and my assumption was incorrect. I did not overwrite viewDidAppear. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there either, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You may want to add [super viewDidAppear:animated]; in HomeViewController's viewDidAppear. Can you also post code where you are popping it.

Comment: I added the call to super. Thanks. I also updated the code with the IBAction to save and pop the controller. I'm tempted to post a video to show everyone the behavior. It's really odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking that the the callbacks in your application delegate are doing something to your view/controller hierarchy.  I would add some break points in your application delegate methods applicationWillResignActive:, applicationDidBecomeActive: and see if they are doing anything.